# Why my imports in minecraft code for mod on Forge don't work?

Tags: java, minecraft, forge

I did Minecraft mod what should add new magnet pickaxe, but for some reason i can't do that because of imports. It just red in Intelij IDEA

there code:

```
package _1;

import net.minecraft.item.PickaxeItem;
import net.minecraft.item.ToolMaterial;

public class MagnetPickaxeItem extends PickaxeItem {

    public <ToolMaterial> MagnetPickaxeItem(ToolMaterial material, Settings settings) {
        super(material, 4, 1.2f, settings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEffectiveOn(net.minecraft.block.BlockState state)
     // add check for netherite blocks
        return state.getBlock() != Blocks.NETHERITE_BLOCK && super.isEffectiveOn(state);
    }
}
```

`

I tried reinstalling the forge and tried libraries for Intelij IDEA, but it doesn't work

Comment: Why are you using `_1` as the package name? What exactly is marked red and what's the exact error? Are you using a build tool? Can you share your build configuration? Can you compile it from the command-line? Also why did you (attempt to) add a `<ToolMaterial>` generic to the constructor (or whatever that is supposed to be)?

Comment: What version of Minecraft is this? What mappings are you using?